# Parallel plate Capacitor - Is it a parallel or Series situation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Assume there is a parallel plate capacitor of length $L$ and width $W$ in which a dielectric materialis inserted up to length $x$ in the capacitor. Assume the plates have charge $Q$  and $-Q$.

The main question is: there are two dielectrics - one air dielectric and other material dielectric.  If I have to find the equivalent capacitance,
**do I need to use the formula for parallel or series combination?**

Because voltage across both the dielectrics will be different, but the charge on the plates is the same, I think it should be the series formula, but I remember in the cases where there is a constant source of voltage, the combination would be considered in parallel, as voltage across them will be same.

[image: This is the Question]

Comment: it was very difficult to find the question

Comment: Please don't paste images of text in the question. Most of it is already typed in. Add whatever you think is missing. This is a homework like question, please add your own attempt of solution. Notice as well how the problem has many important details that you skipped.

Answer (score 2):

If the dielectrics are "side-by side" [the top and bottom of each dielectric touch the conducting plates] then you have the equivalent of two capacitors in **parallel** with the **potential difference** across the dielectrics the **same** [the conducting plates must be equipotentials] but with differing amounts of charge stored on them [the charge is redistributed across the conducting plates].

If the dielectric are on top of one another [the top of one dielectric touches the bottom of the other dielectric] then you have the equivalent of two capacitors in **series** with the **charge stored** on each dielectric the **same** but the potential difference across each of the dielectrics is different.

Comment: I just shared the Question above.. Though i do completely agree with you but according to options given in the Question . None of the answers match when i use series connection.

Comment: So it is a parallel arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

It's like capacitors in parallel because the voltage is the same for each part.

A more fundamental way of looking at it is: if the voltage stays the same, then the electric field across the air-filled part stays the same. But electric field strength parallel to the interface must be continuous and the electric field in the new dielectric is the same and so the displacement field is larger by a factor of the permittivity of the dielectric.

The displacement field is equal to the charge per unit area on the plate (from Gauss's law), so the charge per unit area is also increased by the permittivity in the plate area above the dielectric, whilst above the air-filled part it is unchanged.

Since $C = Q/V$, if the original capacitance was $C_0$ then the new capacitance is just determined by the new charge on the whole plate.
$$ C = C_0(1-f) + f\epsilon_r C_0,$$
where $f$ is the fraction of the plate area sandwiching the dielectric and $\epsilon_r$ is the dielectric relative permittivity (with respect to air).
i.e. This is just the sum of the capacitance of the two parts.